# connecting Odata feed having token based authentication with Power BI without Advance Query Editor

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, powerbi

Thanks in Advance,

i am trying to get the data from Odata Feed to Power BI, my Odata feed is secured with SSO authentication i.e. when i tries to access the data URL in chrome it redirects me to the login page and once i logged in successfully it redirects me to the result of the Odata service.

But some how in the Power BI i am trying to access the same URL it gives me below error:

```
Details: 

"OData: The given URL neither points to an OData service or a feed: 'https://SSOurl/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=/?wtrealm=https://actualOdataURl"
```

i know it is redirecting to the SSo login server and due to that this error is coming.
 
below window i am using to fetch the data.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv9Og.png
```

it ask's me for the Authentication type but SSO type is not present in the Authentication types.

i also know that my Odata service work with Token also so i tried with Advance Query to get the Result like as below:

```
let 
Source = OData.Feed("myOdataURL", null, [Headers = [Authorization = "My token" ] ])
in
Source
```

but i don't want to use the advance Query.

so what changes i'll need to do in my Odata service to get the correct result, without redirecting it to the SSO login server.

Comment: I'm still trying to make heads or tails out of the OAuth flow for a Power BI client [here's an interesting blog post](https://prathy.com/2017/09/calling-power-bi-api-using-power-bi-desktop-to-document-power-bi-service/)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

### Ignore the below answer. This is for creating a custom app or api that can connect and interact with existing Power BI datasets.

ORIGINAL:

I think you need to create an 'app registration' in your Azure Active Directory / azure portal app registrations to represent the Power BI desktop or Excel add-in. [They have a quick way to get it up and running here](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps)

Then, you give THAT app-registration access to your Web API app-registration via the azure portal, and hit the 'Grant Permissions' button

Detailed walkthrough here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app

Will let you know if I succeed.

Comment: Just collecting links here for my own benefit. Here's the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-connect-odata) explaining Power BI desktop to OData .. but it makes no mention of SSO or tokens

Comment: Here's a [more detailed walkthrough](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Desktop-Unable-to-pull-from-OData-feed-using-Token/m-p/129714#M55214) that explains the 'Advanced Editor' technique that the OP states that he doesn't like.